How to calculate percentage of cells with 1 from total cells including those with 0
I wanted to calculate the percentage of total cells with yes to total number of cells with Yes & No. In the image below, I wanted to know how much percentage the 12 yes is in Addis Ababa from the total visited factories(It doesn't count the zeros, that have value No.)No of HPs
I wanted percentage of the count of yes from total column in a pane but it says all 100%

What have you tried so far?

Clarify please -- what is the denominator? Do you want Addis Ababa to be 12 / 59 , i.e. 20.3% or 12 over some other denominator?  To convert numbers to percentages, you have to define what you want exactly as in "Percentage of WHAT". The same table of numbers can lead to different percentages that answer different questions according to your definition

The easiest way to compute percentages in Tableau is to use quick table calcs.
First make a table showing the raw values, so you'll have a green continuous aggregate measure on the Text shelf, say SUM([Sales]) or AVG([Visits]) or COUNTD([Factory]), with likely discrete dimensions on other shelves like Rows or Columns.
To calculate percentages, right click on your Measure field on the Text (or other) shelf. Choose Quick Table Calculation-> Percentage of Total
That is the easy part. Next you need to specify "percentage of WHAT". You do that by right clicking on the field again and changing the "Compute Using" option, or equivalently by choosing "Edit Table Calc" and then changing the partitioning and addressing fields on that dialog.
Read about table calculations in the Tableau documentation to learn more.
You can start to understand how changing "Compute Using" (or equivalently, partitioning and addressing) affects your table calculations by first showing Row and Column grand totals in your table from the Analysis menu - and then trying different settings.
Table calcs take a little time to learn, but are quite useful.
